# Advanced JSON Serialization using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization

I'd like to expand a bit more on this article: http://philcurnow.wordpress.com/2013/12/29/serializing-and-deserializing-json-in-c/

The poster there talks about how to deserialize JSON and to serialize it with an array of objects however they neglect to mention how to do an array of objects within the request.

What I'm looking to do is a little more advanced. I have a set of data that needs to be sent to a server based on a SQL stored procedure. Basically this data is a series of users, their base info, but the API i'm using has those objects in an array within the JSON request because they handle many other users as well with their API.

Clarification added here - This is what I need my final request to look like based off a SQL select stored procedure. The procedure will pull several pieces of data from different tables and databases and compile these items for me. I want the end result to be in this format:

```
{
    "api_key" : "123456XYZBLahBlahBlah",
    "account_id": "12345",
    "recipients": [
            {
                 "first_name": "Sam",
                    "last_name": "Goodfeet",
                 "address1": "123B",
                    "email": "user@test.com",
                    "cellphone": "123-123-1234",
                    "external_db_id": "t12312423"
            },
            {
                  "first_name": "Beth",
                  "last_name": "Goodfeet",
                 "address1": "123B",
                 "email": "user2@test.com",
                 "cellphone": "",
                    "external_db_id": "t45617777"
            }, 
{ recipient #3}, 
{recipient #4}….
        ]
}
```

What i need to do is take my sql table and move it into the JSON structure above. Can I do this with a datatable or dataset or should I create a list based on the dataset? Do I need to create multiple class files to handle the subarray of JSON objects? One for the recipients, and one for the update process request and then serialize them together like this:

```
[DataContract]
class Recipient
{
    [DataMember(Name = "external_db_id")]
    public string nameID { get; set; } //Name id - Required
    [DataMember(Name = "first_name")]
    public string firstname { get ; set; } //First Name Required
    [DataMember(Name = "last_name")]
    public string lastname { get; set; } //Last Name Required
    [DataMember(Name = "address1")]
    public string unitNumber { get; set; } //Unit number - Required
    [DataMember]
    public string email { get; set; } //Email address to notify -Can be blank
    [DataMember]
    public string cellphone { get; set; } //Cell to text - Can be blank
    [DataMember(Name = "pe_alert")]
    public int emailAlert { get; set; } //Email notification preference - Can be blank, if email is not null this defaults to 1
    [DataMember(Name = "pt_alert")]
    public int phoneAlert { get; set; } //Phone notification preference - Can be blank, if cellphone is not null this defaults to 1
}

[DataContract]
class updateRecipientList
{
    [DataMember]
    public string api_key { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string account_id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Recipient recipient { get; set; }
}
```

Or is there another method that might be more viable. Please note I do not want to use the JSON.org libraries. To add that library to our project is not possible. I'm using the internal JSON serialization and deserialization controls that are built into the framework. I'm fairly certain this can be done with those libraries. I'm also forced to framework 3.5 as well.

Additionally, i'd like to know what is the best method for generating the post data for me to send. I have over 1000 entries to send with each request as well. Are there any limitations to the JSON request size I should be aware of? Thanks in advance. I hope I've explained this well.

Comment: I am sure you've made your research and tested this [site](http://json2csharp.com/) before posting the question

Comment: When sending large JSON files, you can zip them and send as zip compressed content.

Comment: l.b. - I have already created the class objects as shown in my code snippets above. My question is related to how to do the actual serialization of the objects into a JSON Request. Perhaps I didn't clarify that enough.

Comment: ilansch - I'm not sure if I can do that or not with this API. They made no mention of accepting compressed content requests. How can I know they can properly receive compressed data and extract it or is this something built into the HTTP POST request that will be done automatically when I post it to the URL? Do you have any link references that outline this process I can use?

Comment: @TylerWalton, HTTP compression is at the HTTP level. Applications don't need to know about it. Try it!

Answer (score 0):

For completeness I did get some help outside here since there wasn't much assistance coming in here. I'll post what I ended up with. I have desensitized the data so you may need to modify it to suit your own use.

```
[DataContract]
class Request
{
    [DataMember]
    public string api_key { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string account_id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Recipient> recipients { get; set; } //THIS is what I missed originally
}

[DataContract]
class Recipient 
{
    [DataMember(Name = "name_id")]
    public string nameID { get; set; } 
    [DataMember(Name = "first_name")]
    public string firstname { get ; set; } 
    [DataMember(Name = "last_name")]
    public string lastname { get; set; } 
    [DataMember(Name = "Unit_number")]
    public string unitNumber { get; set; } 
    [DataMember]
    public string email { get; set; } 
    [DataMember]
    public string cellphone { get; set; }
}

Request request = new Request();

//setup request object
request.account_id = accountID;
request.api_key = apiKey; 
request.recipient = new List<Recipient>(); //Don't forget to do this or you'll have null reference when you add the recipient objects to the request list

//setup connection to stored proc
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("ConnectionStringHere");

//Read data from stored proc
using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedureNameHere", sqlCon))
{
    //setup command type
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    //Open connection
    sqlCon.Open();

    //Execute the reader
    using (SqlDataReader sqlRd = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        //while we still have data keep going
        while (sqlRd.Read())
        {
            Recipient recipient = new Recipient();
            recipient.nameID = sqlRd["column1"].ToString();
            recipient.unitNumber = sqlRd["column2"].ToString().Trim(); //example of trimming out white space
            recipient.firstname = sqlRd["column3"].ToString();
            recipient.lastname = sqlRd["column4"].ToString();
            recipient.email = sqlRd["column5"].ToString();
            recipient.cellphone = Regex.Replace(sqlRd["column6"].ToString(), "[^.0-9]", ""); //example of setting the value to only numbers removing anything else

            //store recipient to request object
            request.recipients.Add(recipient); //This will put the items in the object for proper serialization based on the object structure
        }
    } 

    //finished close connection
    sqlCon.Close();
}

//serialize dataset into JSON request
string jsonString = SerializeJSon<Request>(request); //Link to function for this code can be found in the original question
```

Once you do that, you can easily post the information to whatever service you want to. There's some code on how to do that in the original article as well I linked in the question.

I basically decided to go with a list of recipient objects within the request object instead of setting the data to a dataset and then to an object. Instead I loop through the data set using the datareader to add each recipient to the request object as it goes through the data. I had in my initial test about 500 users and in the end after full integration is complete we'll probably have over 160,000 recipients. If I run into problems with that I'll comment here. I'm still unsure about the JSON request size limitations. I did not integrate any kind of compression as ilansch referred to above but it may require that for large data sets.

Basically when you serialize the request object using the serialization process code from the post I linked on my original question it will basically decode the fact you have a sub-array of recipients in the request object and create the JSON array of recipients within the request formatting exactly as I outlined I wanted it to look. The original article code is solid for that process so I recommend using that code. It saved me a significant amount of time and headache.

The only downside to this I think will be that it ties up the SQL server while its looping through the dataset. I had wanted to originally set the data to a dataset then move that object data to the request object but this was far simpler and it felt more streamlined. I don't know if there's a more efficient way to relieve load off the SQL server itself and put more load on the code base (I personally would prefer that). So you may want to keep this in the back of your head when using this code if you're using a very large set of data. In my situation here I think it will only allow the connection to close only a fraction sooner if I used that method. Obviously it will probably exponentially increase as the amount of data read into memory is increased. Depending on the data size you may consider modifying this to do that instead of leaving the connection open and creating the object information as it reads the data.

At any rate, I hope this helps someone in the future.